# LEFT join not returning all rows from LEFT table

Tags: excel, vba, sql-server-2005, left-join

This topic seems to come up a bit but none of the answers I’ve found have worked for me.

I want to join two tables taking all the values from table DAYS which is one column of numbers 1 to 30 and a column concatenating values from a second table called DATA as below:

```
Ref  Week_Comm  Date        Name            Adj_Type      Hours Description Sick_Note   Deleted

223  04-Apr-17  04-Apr-17   Joe Bloggs      Absence          4  Sickness    RECD    
112  04-Apr-17  05-Apr-17   Joe Bloggs      Absence          7  Sickness    RECD    
196  04-Apr-17  06-Apr-17   Joe Bloggs      Absence          7  Sickness    RECD    
197  11-Apr-17  11-Apr-17   Fred Flintstone Holiday          7
```

My desired results would look something like this:

```
Day         April
1   
2   
3   
4           A 4Hrs
5           A 7Hrs
6           A 7Hrs
7   
8
etc to 30
```

The concatenation works well but I only get a result from where there is a match with the right table.

I’m creating the SQL in Excel VBA as a string and using an ODBC connection to return the data. The tables are contained within the same spreadsheet.

My first attempt was as follows

```
SELECT DAYS.Day, (LEFT(DATA.Adj_Type,1) + ' ' + Cstr(DATA.Hours) + ' Hrs') as April 
FROM DAYS 
LEFT OUTER JOIN DATA ON (DAYS.Day = DAY(DATA.Date) 
WHERE (MONTH(DATA.Date)=4) AND (DATA.Deleted Is Null) AND (DATA.Name='Joe Blogs')) 
ORDER BY DAYS.Day
```

This gives me results for an inner join i.e. it doesn’t return all the values from my left table DAYS

Following answers to similar questions on this forum I tried replacing WHERE with AND as follows

```
SELECT DAYS.Day, (LEFT(DATA.Adj_Type,1) + ' ' + Cstr(DATA.Hours) + ' Hrs') as April 
FROM DAYS 
LEFT OUTER JOIN DATA ON ((DAYS.Day = DAY(DATA.Date) 
AND  (MONTH(DATA.Date)=4) AND (DATA.Deleted Is Null) AND (DATA.Name='Joe Blogs')) 
ORDER BY DAYS.Day
```

This returns no data and I get the error “JOIN EXPRESSION NOT SUPPORTED”

I then tried selecting the data I wanted for my tables and then joining them:

```
SELECT DAYS.Day 
FROM DAYS AS A 
LEFT JOIN (SELECT DAY(DATA.Date) AS Day, (LEFT(DATA.Adj_Type,1) + ' ' + Cstr(DATA.Hours) + ' Hrs') as April 
FROM DATA
WHERE (MONTH(DATA.Date)=4) AND (DATA.Deleted Is Null) AND (DATA.Name='Joe Blogs')) as B 
ON A.Day = B.Day
```

And I get the error message

> Syntax error in FROM clause

Where am I going wrong?? I’m very novice at all this and get most of my info via google

Thanks in advance - Justin

EDIT I've edited out the extra alias names (as above) but am still getting the same results.

Comment: it seems that your tables are named DAYS and DATA, why do you repeating DATA DATA and DAYS DAYS in FROM clause?

Comment: As marcinszaleniec commented but particularly re this line FROM DAYS DAYS AS A    , you're aliasing twice

Comment: Any time you reference the *right* table, you need to use the join clause, not the where clause. If you use a filter against the right table in the where clause, it turns your outer join into an inner join, because the only way it can know whether the value there matches your filter is if there is a matching row. Of course you need to get the basic syntax down first. Why are you aliasing DAYS as DAYS (or A)?

Comment: I've always used the DATA DATA syntax I think it came from using ms query.

Comment: I've deleted that now and am still getting syntax error in FROM clause I'm now using     SELECT DAYS.Day  FROM DAYS AS A    LEFT JOIN (SELECT DAY(DATA.Date) AS Day, (LEFT(DATA.Adj_Type,1) + ' ' + Cstr(DATA.Hours) + ' Hrs') as April    FROM DATA    WHERE (MONTH(DATA.Date)=4) AND (DATA.Deleted Is Null) AND (DATA.Name='Joe Blogs') )
as B
    ON A.Day = B.Day

Comment: What is "FROM DATA" doing in there? Maybe you could start over by showing your table definitions, some sample data, and desired results. I can't work out from your incorrect syntax what your actual query is trying to do...

Comment: Thanks Aaron for your offer of help I will post again in a couple of days.

Comment: Hi Aaron I've added an example of the right table in my question and an example of my desired results. Hope you can help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is now solved. The second SQL statement in my question was in fact correct but because it was taking null data from the left table into my concatenated string it wasn't bringing any data back because of an "invalid use of null" error. I had thought the concatenation had been working ok but this was only on the statements that excluded the Null data through the incorrect use of WHERE.

Here is my final code.

```
SELECT DAYS.Day, IIF(DATA.Hours is null, DATA.Hours, (LEFT(DATA.Adj_Type,1) + ' ' + Cstr(DATA.Hours) + ' Hrs')) 
FROM DAYS LEFT OUTER JOIN DATA ON (DAYS.Day = DAY(DATA.Date) AND (MONTH(DATA.Date)=4) AND (DATA.Deleted Is Null) AND (DATA.Name='Joe Bloggs')) 
ORDER BY DAYS.Day
```

Hope this may help someone else in the future.

Answer (score 0):

Your second query is on the right track, only `MONTH(DATA.Date)=4` can't be used in a join condition. Instead move it back to the WHERE clause like this:

```
WHERE (MONTH(DATA.Date)=4 OR DATA.Date IS NULL)
```

Comment: Thanks ItsLex -  I just tried the following but no data was returned is this how you mean?
`SELECT DAYS.Day 
FROM DAYS AS A 
LEFT JOIN (SELECT DAY(DATA.Date) AS Day, (LEFT(DATA.Adj_Type,1) + ' ' + Cstr(DATA.Hours) + ' Hrs') as April 
FROM Data 
WHERE (MONTH(DATA.Date)=4) OR (DATA.Date IS NULL) AND (DATA.Deleted Is Null) AND (DATA.Name=’Joe Blogs) ) 
as B
ON A.Day = B.Day`

Comment: No, that's your third query. And mind your brackets around the OR statements.

Comment: I've tried WHERE (MONTH(DATA.Date)=4)  AND (DATA.Deleted Is Null) AND (DATA.Name='Joe Bloggs') OR (DATA.Date IS NULL) which just returns the inner join values again.

Comment: And finally I've tried WHERE (MONTH(DATA.Date)=4 OR DATA.Date IS NULL) AND (DATA.Deleted Is Null) AND (DATA.Name='Joe Bloggs') and again get an inner join.

Comment: My understanding is that I can't use the WHERE clause on the right table. But I'm sure there must be a way.